# Flex date formatting XML result

Tags: xml, apache-flex, date, formatting

I am retrieving a twitter feed using a php file and it is returning the XML, however the date XML field is..

```
<created_at>Sun Nov 08 07:26:07 +0000 2009</created_at>
```

I am calling this inside flex from my

```
[Bindable] public var twitterData:XMLList;
```

using `{data.created_at}` how would I format this to read as a normal date? (i.e Sun Nov 08 2009) or similar.

EDIT:

i have done the following but now nothing is showing, i believe the dateformatter is only for dates whereas i have allot more info in the string.

```
<mx:DateFormatter id="formatDateTime" formatString="DD/MM/YYY" />
<mx:Label width="100%" text="{formatDateTime.format(data.created_at)}" fontWeight="bold" color="#FFAE00"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array to split it by spaces:

```
private function formatedDate(date:String):String{
   var arr:Array = date.split(/\s/);
   return arr[0] + " " + arr[1] + " " + arr[2] + " " + arr[5];
}
```

and then bind it to a label

```
<mx:Label text="{formatedDate(data.created_at)}" />
```

I've tried using DateFormatter and Date and I was unsuccesful, DateFormatter and Date both need a DD/MM/YYYY format for input string.

Comment: `labelText = str[0] + " " + str[1] + " " + str[2] + " " + str[5];`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you might take a look at the DateFormatter object.  [http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/)/

That lets you set up your own conversion from string input to date - just like what zombiegx suggests, but with a more flexibility.  The initial conversion returns a string, but that can be converted to a Date object via the parseDateString method.

Comment: i believe the string i am passing it has to much data in it and the formatter cannot handle it. plus as zombiegx pointed out the date has words in it instead of numbers for month / day etc...

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem, really, for the date to have words if you're using a DateFormatter.  It's easier if everything is numbers, but you can make a DateFormatter that uses strings.  The DateFormatter has a helper object called a DateBase which contains info for day names and month names.  You can create your own DateBase object, as well, if you need to.  

I don't have enough time to put up a meaningful chunk of code right now - but if I find some time soon, I will.